# Order by best match in eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have some results which I get from the eloquent query, and I want to order them by best match. How can I do it in laravel eloquent?

here I found some solution in SQL, but I could not use it in the eloquent builder.

```
    SELECT TOP 5 * 
    FROM Products
    WHERE ProductCode LIKE '%200%'
    ORDER BY CHARINDEX('200', ProductCode, 1), ProductCode
```

https://bytutorial.com/blogs/tsql/how-to-order-the-sql-query-result-by-best-match-keyword-search

Comment: You can use `orderByRaw` https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: it helps. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as suggested, you can use `orderByRaw()` So your query would be transformed Like:

```
$result = Product::where("ProductCode", "LIKE", '%200%')
                ->orderByRaw('CHARINDEX('200', ProductCode, 1) DESC, ProductCode ASC')
                ->get();
```

Here, it supposed, the model name is `Product` for table `products`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use raw query to order by best match. Its given me best match results.

```
DB::select(
    "SELECT *
       FROM  table_name
       WHERE column_name LIKE '%".$search_word."%' 
       ORDER BY
        CASE
        WHEN column_name LIKE '".$search_word."' THEN 1
        WHEN column_name LIKE '".$search_word."%' THEN 2
        WHEN column_name LIKE '%".$search_word."%' THEN 3
        WHEN column_name LIKE '%".$search_word."' THEN 4
        ELSE 5
    END")
```

The matched result will be sorted by the below order.

- **First Case:** Exact match with search word.
- **Second Case:** Starting with search word.
- **Third Case:**  Search word in any position.
- **Fourth Case:** Ending with search word.
- **ELSE Case:** Search word does not contains.