# Laravel eloquent search and order by best matching

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a `products` table in my ecommerce website. When customers search products by `name`, I execute the following query:

> `$products = Product::where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')->get();`

Now, I see the result contains only matched rows with customer's `$query`. But the result is not ordered by the best matching as like google. How should I change my query to get products ordered by best matching?

Comment: Is this your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56573629/order-by-best-match-in-eloquent

Comment: No. The answer does not emphasizes on multiple matches.

Comment: You should use MySql Full Text Search. Check this link for more info: https://severalnines.com/database-blog/full-text-searches-mysql-good-bad-and-ugly

Comment: There are also some libraries also for Laravel in order to do a Full Text Search

Answer (score 1):

First of all, best match is a bit ambiguous.

However any solution will always include the usage of multiple `orderByRaw` calls.

Example:

```
$products = Product::where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orderByRaw('name like ? desc', $query)
            ->orderByRaw('instr(name,?) asc', $query)
            ->orderBy('name')
            ->get();
```

Basically, it orders on the name match first (still using `like` to allow wildcards in the search string, if not needed use `=`).

Then it orders the substring position of the query it found in the `name` col, make sure to order `asc` since lower is better. At least in my definition of best match.

**Also notice the usage of the `?` parameter.** Using it like this `->orderByRaw('name like '.$query.' desc')` will make it vulnerable to SQL injection!

Take into account that ordering on multiple subqueries can be costly!